# Get average interval between pairs of rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, psql

I have a table with the following data (paypal transactions):

```
    txn_type    |            date            |   subscription_id
----------------+----------------------------+---------------------
 subscr_signup  | 2014-01-01 07:53:20        | S-XXX01
 subscr_signup  | 2014-01-05 10:37:26        | S-XXX02
 subscr_signup  | 2014-01-08 08:54:00        | S-XXX03
 subscr_eot     | 2014-03-01 08:53:57        | S-XXX01
 subscr_eot     | 2014-03-05 08:58:02        | S-XXX02
```

I want to get the average subscription length overall for a given time period (`subscr_eot` is the end of a subscription). In the case of a subscription that is still ongoing (`'S-XXX03'`) I want it to be included from it's start date until *now* in the average.
How would I go about doing this with an SQL statement in Postgres?

Comment: Isn't either the beginning date or the end date missing ?

Comment: The beginning date is subscr_signup. So for example S-XXX01 beginning date is 2014-01-01 and end date 2014-03-01

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. If you talking about the date range it could be anything, ie. 2014-01-01 - now.

Comment: Could you please post the expected output...

Comment: The expected output would be the average amount of days a subscription has been active. In this case if our date range was 2014-01-01 to 2014-04-24 the average subscription length would be 75.7 days (60 days + 60 days + 107 days)/3 subscriptions

Comment: "average subscription length would be 75.7 days (60 days + 60 days + 107 days)/3" - How this 60 days come, i mean is it 1 month days or what ?? and how this 107 days you calculate ???

Comment: @OP Please edit your question to include the expected output, and explain how you calculate the time differences because it's apparently not obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c862e/2). Subscription length for each subscription:

```
select
    subscription_id,
    coalesce(t2.date, current_timestamp) - t1.date as subscription_length
from
    (
        select *
        from t
        where txn_type = 'subscr_signup'
    ) t1
    left join
    (
        select *
        from t
        where txn_type = 'subscr_eot'
    ) t2 using (subscription_id)
order by t1.subscription_id
```

The average:

```
select
    avg(coalesce(t2.date, current_timestamp) - t1.date) as subscription_length_avg
from
    (
        select *
        from t
        where txn_type = 'subscr_signup'
    ) t1
    left join
    (
        select *
        from t
        where txn_type = 'subscr_eot'
    ) t2 using (subscription_id)
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar, but this is clearer. Very nice.

Comment: Same for me (damn you, subway from work to home !). +1

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was unaware of the coalesce function. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I used a couple of common table expressions; you can take the pieces apart pretty easily to see what they do.

One of the reasons this SQL is complicated is because you're storing column names as data. (subscr_signup and subscr_eot are actually column names, not data.) This is a SQL anti-pattern; expect it to cause you much pain.

```
with subscription_dates as (
  select 
      p1.subscription_id, 
      p1.date as subscr_start,
      coalesce((select min(p2.date) 
                from paypal_transactions p2
                where p2.subscription_id = p1.subscription_id
                  and p2.txn_type = 'subscr_eot'
                  and p2.date > p1.date), current_date) as subscr_end
  from paypal_transactions p1
  where txn_type = 'subscr_signup'
), subscription_days as (
  select subscription_id, subscr_start, subscr_end, (subscr_end - subscr_start) + 1 as subscr_days
  from subscription_dates 
)
select avg(subscr_days) as avg_days
from subscription_days
-- add your date range here.

avg_days
--
75.6666666666666667
```

I didn't add your date range as a WHERE clause, because it's not clear to me what you mean by "a given time period".

Answer (score 0):

Using the [window function **`lag()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html), this becomes considerably shorter:

```
SELECT avg(ts_end - ts) AS avg_subscr
FROM  (
   SELECT txn_type, ts, lag(ts, 1, localtimestamp)
                OVER (PARTITION BY subscription_id ORDER BY txn_type) AS ts_end
   FROM  t
   ) sub
WHERE txn_type = 'subscr_signup';
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9ee3/2)

`lag()` conveniently takes a default value for missing rows. *Exactly* what we need here, so we don't need [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in addition.

The query builds on the fact that `subscr_eot` sorts before `subscr_signup`.

Probably faster than presented alternatives so far because it only needs a single sequential scan - even though the window functions add some cost.

Using the column `ts` instead of `date` for three reasons:

- Your "date" is actually a `timestamp`.
- "date" is a reserved word in standard SQL (even if it's allowed in Postgres).
- Never use basic type names as identifiers.

Using `localtimestamp` instead of `now()` or `current_timestamp` since you are obviously operating with [`timestamp [without time zone]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170).

Also, your columns `txn_type` and `subscription_id` should not be `text`
Maybe an [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html) for `txn_type` and `integer` for `subscription_id`. That would make table and indexes considerably smaller and faster.

For the query at hand, the whole table has to be read an **indexes** won't help - except for a `covering index` in Postgres 9.2+, if you need the read performance:

```
CREATE INDEX t_foo_idx ON t (subscription_id, txn_type, ts);
```